# Jenkins pipeleine: execute remote script: error: line 1: html: No such file or directory

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am totally new to jenkins and groovy. Suddenly our jenkins pipelines are failing! This has never happened earlier!

This is the simplified pipeline script -

```
stages 
    {
        stage('1. Preparation of Environment') 
        {
            steps 
            {
                container('maven') 
                {
                    script 
                    {
                        utilsScript = load 'jenkinsUtils.groovy'
                        cspVersion = utilsScript.latestVersionOf('com.xyz.ria.parent', 'xyz-ria-parent', "${params.CSP_VERSION}_*", MAVEN_CANDIDATES_REPO)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the remote jenkinsUtils.groovy file -

```
String latestVersionOf(group, artifact, version, repo) {
    script {
      return sh (
        returnStdout: true,
        script: "curl -su 'restapi:restapi' '${ARTIFACTORY_URL}/api/search/latestVersion?g=${group}&a=${artifact}&v=${version}&repos=${repo}'"
      )
    }
  }
  
return this
```

Jenkins trace file shows the following -

```
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
21:24:49  + curl -su restapi:restapi 'repo.lab.pl.xyz.com/api/search/latestVersion?g=com.xyz.ria.parent&a=xyz-ria-parent&v=2020.1_*&repos=foff-mvn-candidates-local'
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] sh
21:24:51  + echo
21:24:51  /home/jenkins/workspace/DigitalOperations/FlowOne/sri/9_Deploy_SRI_Air_Client/airclient@tmp/durable-d9368f0e/script.sh: line 1: html: No such file or directory
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

I have cheked that the output of the curl command is indeed returning proper value. But the script is failing! This was working fine 4 months back, but suddenly this issue has occurred. Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: check what you have in `durable-d9368f0e/script.sh` - seems error coming from this script

Comment: Hi @daggett: how to check it's content? As per my understanding it's the temporary file that is generated after calling the remote script. The return script is the temporary file. How to check it's content?

Comment: as for me, the  shell that is failing - the one after `curl ...` maybe because curl returns html instead of some value. try to add `set -ev` at the beginning of each `sh` script.

Answer (score 0):

Finally our support team has solved the issue.

They found that actually the curl calls were getting redirected and we need to follow these redirects. We modified the curl command with the extra **-L** option and now it's working fine.

```
curl -L -su 'restapi:restapi' '${ARTIFACTORY_URL}/api/search/latestVersion?g=${group}&a=${artifact}&v=${version}&repos=${repo}'
```

May be someone sometime down the line will be helpful with this info ...

Thanks